# React best practices - default props on both parent and child components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component Foo that passes down a prop `color` to its child Bar:

```
const Foo = ({ color }) => ( 
  <Bar color={color} />      
)
```

Bar has default props for its prop `color`. Is there any need for Foo to also assign default props for its own prop `color`? Will it help make Foo's own contract clear?

Comment: Not enough known about use case to answer this

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not sure which details would be helpful to include. Can you give an example of when it might be necessary for Foo and Bar to both assign default props for color?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *"assign default props"*

Comment: Bar.defaultProps = {
  color: 'red',
};
Foo.defaultProps = {
  color: 'red',
};

Comment: Would depend on if they may not get passed to `Foo`. Can do a simple `if()` inside Foo

Comment: Yes, in this situation Foo will usually not get a color prop, because most of the time we want the default red color.

Comment: In this situation do you think it is or is not helpful to have Foo.defaultProps = { color: 'red', }; in addition to Bar.defaultProps = { color: 'red', };?

Comment: Probably no need to duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your help